# what does [0,:] mean in matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to debug this code from my lecture so that it will run on my computer (Win10). When run in terminal I get the first image that is defined by the `plt.figure()` section but the animation part never runs. I get an error code related to pillows instead.

I have downloaded ffmep using pip and have also updated my matplotlib the same way.

Here is the code:

```
if plot_flag == True:
    res = []
    for i in range(N):
        res.append(np.array(list_particles[i].pos))

if plot_flag == True:
    ### display one trajectory
    pos = res[0]
    plt.plot(pos[:,0],pos[:,1],'k-')
    plt.show()

    ###produce an animation 
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(0, L), ylim=(0, L))
    ax.grid()

    patch=[]
    for i in range(N):
        patch.append(plt.Circle(res[i][0,:],list_particles[i].radius,fc="r"))
        ax.add_patch(patch[i])


    def animate(i):
        for j in range(N):
            x,y=res[j][i,:]
            patch[j].center= (x,y)


    def init():
        line.set_data([], [])
        time_text.set_text('')
        return line, time_text

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(0, Niter),
                            interval=25, blit=False)
    ani.save("gas.mp4",fps=25)
```

I am meant to get an animation after I close the figure window but I get error messages instead:

```
MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable. Trying to use pillow instead.
```

which means nothing to either me or the internet. Most of this code I can understand apart from `res[i][0,:]` (line 16) which doesn't make any sense to me, at first I thought the comma shouldn't be there but the same syntax is repeated on line 21: `x,y=res[j][i,:]`.

I also cannot run this code in spyder as I get a deprecated() error which seams to block even debug running usefully.

Can someone help me understand what is going on because I am utterly lost now,
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first output means it cannot find ffmpeg (or parts of it). So you either did not install it correctly or you have to tell it where to find it (I have no idea how, on Windows).

[`pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/) is an image manipulation library (it is a drop-in replacement for [PIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library), the Python Image Library), which it tries to use instead.

---

The second syntax is [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) [slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html), which is how you can index a multi-dimensional array. Slices work just like in normal Python, except that the slices for each dimension are separated by commas.

So `x[0,:]` means take the first entry along the first dimension (which is a row, since the object seems to have two dimensions in total) and then take all entries along the second dimension (so the whole first row).

And `pos[:,1]` means take all entries along the first dimension (so all rows), but for each row take only the second entry along the second dimension (so it selects the whole second column).

Comment: ok thank you for clearing that up, ill look into ways of showing the pc how to find the module, thats very helpfull